# Can't rename the keyboard layout made in MSKLC

Tags: windows, keyboard, windows-registry, keyboard-layout

So I made a custom keyboard layout in MSKLC (Microsoft Keyboard Layout Creator). Its default naming scheme is adding `- Custom` to the name of the layout you modified, e.g. `Serbian (Cyrillic) - Custom`.

When needed, I modify the layout again, uninstall the old one and install the new one (and rename it, to keep track of which version it is). But for some reason, Windows seems to keep the old name, no matter how many times I reinstall the layout.

I checked the registry entry in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Control\Keyboard Layouts`. It also had the old name in the `Layout Text` key. I renamed it, but Windows still displays the old name.

So if not in the registry, where does Windows keep the old name, and how do I change it?

If it's relevant, I have 64-bit Windows 8.1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to edit the .klc file manually with a text editor, because there's no way to edit the name that displays from within the MSKLC program, unfortunately, for this feature was mistakenly not coded into the app. Therefore,

1. Uninstall the previous keyboard you have installed in Windows
2. Right-click the .klc file, open it with a text editor.
3. Search for the old name that you wanted to update (it was located near the end of the .klc file in my case).
4. Just edit that old name and nothing else in the file, then save the file.
5. Open the .klc file in MSKLC, check Project > "Properties..." to see if the metadata is all correct. In particular, there should be no spaces in the Name field, or the keyboard will not build (the potential error will be logged in the log file during validation before building).
6. Build the keyboard (Project > Build DLL and Setup Package). Install the setup file that was created.

The name should be updated now, God willing.

Comment: This is a working answer still in July 2021 for Windows 10, Version 2004 build 19041.1110. I will add a tag of Windows 10 to the question. Strange that the OP did accept the answer but did not even give it one "useful"... So thank you @naush for writing this up.