# How can I make Windows show a different name for my custom keyboard layout?

Tags: windows, windows-10, keyboard, keyboard-layout, microsoft-klc

I made a keyboard layout with the Microsoft Keyboard Layout Creator, and added a name and description (see pic).
[layout description window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FE9g7.png)

After building the layout, the generated dll files had the correct name, so I figured everything was good. However, Windows still defaults to "Spanish - Custom Keyboard". [list of keyboard layouts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zeysR.png)

I was then able to find the registry entry for my layout at `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Keyboard Layouts\a001080a`

The "Layout Text" key had in its Data field "Spanish - Custom Keyboard", so I assumed that must be where the dialog was pulling that phrase from.
[registry window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZUKpP.png)
Changed it to the name I want for my layout, rebooted my computer, and STILL the name has not been updated.

Is there somewhere else this value is stored? Or some way to force the dialog to fetch the new value I've given it?

Comment: Duplicate, apparently. Didn't find [this other identical question](https://superuser.com/questions/1470086/cant-rename-the-keyboard-layout-made-in-msklc?rq=1) until after posting this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Self-resolved. Went back to the registry entry for my keyboard layout and edited the "Layout Display Name". It contained a reference to a line in the dll file where the name was held. I just hard-coded in the name I wanted to be shown, and now it works. [registry entry](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jLgNV.png)

Comment: I don't know how to edit dlls, is it not possible instead of writing a reference to the dll to put the name in a string in the registry entry? (I tried but it doesn't work)