# How to add an inscription to custom keyboard layout, that appears on control panel?

Tags: windows, keyboard, keyboard-layout, microsoft-klc

Does anybody know how to add a second name for custom keyboard layout, that appears under the main name on the control panel, like `US` under `ENG` for "English (United States)"? [Displays when clicking on control panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ctDUX.png). [Displays on the control panel when there are a few layouts for one language](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fmDUu.png)

I made a few layouts for one language via `MSKLC` and I don't see which I use looking on the control panel.

I assume that it can be done via "Registry Editor", but I didn't find anything except "display name" in path:`Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Keyboard Layouts\00000409`, but it's not it, this is only the description.
Also how to add an inscription that appears in settings like `QWERTY`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't rename the keyboard layout made in MSKLC](https://superuser.com/questions/1470086/cant-rename-the-keyboard-layout-made-in-msklc)

Comment: Not. This is the name that is displayed when you click on language on the control panel → under the language → Keyboard US. This is written in 3rd paragraph. I need to know how to display 'US' on the control panel when there are a few layouts for English. It assumes here that I am making this layout. Sry for my English if something is unclearly written.

Comment: When I looked into this a few years ago, the list of second texts was hardcoded in the language panel dll with no apparent way to change it.

Comment: Yeh, I thought so